# gae php helloworld gives white screen with local server on gce debian and centos instance

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, centos6

i am trying to run the gae php hellowrold on a gce debian and or gce centos instance.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld

the helloworld example produces PHP's white screen of death when running on gce debian and gce centos systems. each instance is a new build created in the last 48 hours.

my latest build was centos so i will describe that env.

Python:

```
[stephen@skc-php-dev-centos-00 ~]$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
[stephen@skc-php-dev-centos-00 ~]$ python -V
Python 2.7.6
[stephen@skc-php-dev-centos-00 ~]$
```

PHP:

```
[stephen@skc-php-dev-centos-00 bin]$ ./php -v
PHP 5.4.15 (cli) (built: Dec 10 2013 20:31:32) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
[stephen@skc-php-dev-centos-00 bin]$
```

google_appengine:

```
[stephen@skc-php-dev-centos-00 google_appengine]$ cat VERSION
release: "1.8.8"
timestamp: 1383722570
api_versions: ['1']
supported_api_versions:
 python:
    api_versions: ['1']
 python27:
   api_versions: ['1']
 go:
  api_versions: ['go1']
[stephen@skc-php-dev-centos-00 google_appengine]$
```

the command to start the helloworld:

```
 /home/stephen/skc-local/google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/home/stephen/skc-local/bin/php /home/stephen/code/google-php/helloworld
```

the server starts fine:

```
WARNING  2013-12-11 10:58:47,524 api_server.py:331] Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-12-11 10:58:47,538 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at:      http://localhost:40256
INFO     2013-12-11 10:58:47,556 dispatcher.py:171] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2013-12-11 10:58:47,557 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2013-12-11 10:59:33,646 module.py:617] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
INFO     2013-12-11 10:59:33,702 module.py:617] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

when i hit the server i get a 200 response, however when i access the server

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

the only thing i see is the dreaded PHP white screen of death.

it seems that the dev server does not have any error logging.

my code:
helloworld.php

```
<?php
   echo 'Hello, World!';
```

app.yaml

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.php
```

i have followed the instructions very closely; at this point i all most know them by heart.

any insight or recommendations will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

> /home/stephen/skc-local/google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py
>   --php_executable_path=/home/stephen/skc-local/bin/php /home/stephen/code/google-php/helloworld

Try changing the executable from `php` to `php-cgi`.. so that it looks like this:

> /home/stephen/skc-local/google/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py
>   --php_executable_path=/home/stephen/skc-local/bin/php-cgi /home/stephen/code/google-php/helloworld